# Eureka Discovery by random client

Tags: netflix-eureka

Lets say I have x amount of instances for a microservice. They all register with a Eureka server.

Some random user wants to make use of this microservice to fetch some data. Obviously they can pick an instance to use. But if they want to use the Eureka discovery service, do they have to implement a Eureka client? If so, how to prevent them from registering to the Eureka server?

Would it be best to create a "master service" that implements a Eureka client for this random user call so they don't have to worry about Eureka at all? Does below diagram make sense?

[image: Random client fetch data]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the Eureka Discovery service, but in general most web services will have you sign up for an API token. The API token should then be used by the microservice to make requests to the Eureka Discovery service on the end user's behalf. The "random client" does not need to know about the Eureka Discovery service or how to communicate with it, it should only know how to communicate with your microservice. Using some kind of "master service" would defeat the purpose of a microservice architecture which is primarily scalability, a "master service" would most likely become a bottleneck.

In general you would expect to see an application designed with a microservice architecture configured as follows:

[image]

Obviously is a very basic example, it does not consider persistence, caching, etc. But it should give you the basic idea.